# jquery: select all siblings with css left:position greater than left:position of an element

Tags: jquery, position, siblings

How to select all siblings of an element that are positioned to the right of it via css?
[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6GVBc/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to return a subset of a selector based on a function you provide, try this:

```
var threeLeft = $("#three").position().left;
var $lis = $("ul li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).position().left > threeLeft;
});
$lis.css("border", "1px solid #C00");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6GVBc/1/)

Comment: Perfect - Figured I needed a filter but couldn't work out the position() bit. Thanks a lot Rory - appreciate your help.